# PDO Can't catch exception which is thrown

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

Ok so I can't catch the exeption:

```
require_once 'config/config.php';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASS,array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Unable to connect!: " . $e->getMessage() . BR;
    die();
}

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,email FROM no_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindColumn('email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
        echo $id . "\t" . $email . BR;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Ok I connect I have an error in the syntax (there isn't any no_table) it throws the exception but i can't catch it. In browser I see this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]:
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'no_table' doesn't exist' in 'somepath'
PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in some.php on line 15
```

The exception is thrown and i can't catch it, but if I put another try catch between `$stmt->execute();` it catches it.

My php version 5.3.14

Comment: Apart from the problem - why do you want to catch it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your code. It does catch for me all right

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. php version 5.4

Comment: Because it ruins all my script if there is any problem with this query the exeption is thrown but couldn't be catched and my script stops so to countinue i need to catch it somehow

Comment: can you paste your real script to pastebin or something. this small condensed version might not have the real reason

Comment: man this is all my code it isn't from somewhere else

Comment: Are you sure this script is completely standalone? As it currently stands, your problem can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 9):

Have you been using namespaced classes in this project maybe?
If so, please try to use

```
\PDOException
```

instead of

```
PDOException
```

in your "catch" statement.
I just got similar problem and this move helped.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.